# passing variable to jquery click function

Tags: jquery

Hi I need to pass the  id variable from the following hyperlink to a jquery click function

Here is the link

```
<a id='howdy' href='#' course_id = 5>Howdy</a>
```

And here is the click function that I attempted to utilize:

```
$('a#howdy').click(function(e){
  $.get('insert_courses.php' + data.course_id, function(data){
    modal.open({content: data});
  });
});
```

I need the correct syntax to put in place of

```
+ data.course_id
```

as this doesn't seem to work thanks

Comment: two time `id` is invalid.Use `data-id` for second-one

Answer (score 0):

Change the current code to

```
$('a#howdy').click(function(e){
    $.get('insert_courses.php?id=' + $(this).attr("course_id"), function(data){
    modal.open({content: data});
    });
});
```

Here you go with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4asa95cw/1/

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to access the `course-id` attribute if the element.

```
 <a id='howdy' href='#' course_id = 5>Howdy</a>

     $('a#howdy').click(function(e){
            $.get('insert_courses.php' + $('#howdy).attr('course-id'), function(data){
            modal.open({content: data});
            });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should ideally use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), to get the relevant attribute. That's the correct way of using JQuery and also the way in which additional attributes can be set/get in your DOM. Check the API for more details: https://api.jquery.com/data/

And below is your updated code, using `data()`:

```js
$('a#howdy').click(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).data("course-id"));
  $.get('insert_courses.php?id=' + $(this).data("course-id"), function(data) {
    modal.open({
      content: data
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='howdy' href='#' data-course-id=5>Howdy</a>
```